# How to handle timeout in queries with Firebase

Tags: firebase

I noticed that if I execute a query in Firebase and the database server is not reachable, the callback waits just forever (or until the server is reachable again).

Where this behavior is quite natural for the asynchronous approach used, it would nevertheless be useful to have an easy way to specify a timeout so you could inform the user about the status.

Is there such an option and I just missed it - or it really missing?
Or how would you solve this problem?

Comment: If you're trying to detect whether the user is connected to the Firebase server, have a look at [`.info/connected`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-connection-state).

Comment: Was facing the same problem. Finally put timer around the query to mark it as timedout. Whole process was easy to do using Boltz framework for maintaining tasks (BFTask), specially in case where you are dealing with multiple queries.

Comment: The link mentioned by Frank has been updated to https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state.

Answer (score 3):

you can manage yourself a timer controller that after x seconds remove the listener to you firebase reference. It's very simple, just one line of code in android for example.

You can see the code for the web (Detaching Callbacks section):
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html

or for android (Detaching Callbacks section):
https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-detaching

same section for IOS ;)

Comment: observeSingleEventOfType, with this we don't get a handle and hence won't be able to detach the callback.

Answer (score 3):

As per today there is no timeout concept on those listeners. One option is to manage the timeout yourself.

This is how I do it when I also want to display a progress dialog while loading the content.

```
    private void showProgressDialog(boolean show, long time) {
    try {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            if (show) {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
                progressDialog.show();
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if(progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(ActPreguntas.this, "Couldn't connect, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, time);
            } else {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```

So when you make a request to Firebase you call showProgressDialog(true,5000) and after 5 seconds if the dialog stills there is because it could not connect and you then do what you have to as per the timeout.

On the callback of the Firebase listener you do this showProgressDialog(false,0)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Isn't it better to remove the listener on completing five seconds? Alternatively, we can bake in the timeout feature into the request itself instead of tying it to a UI component.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution for the Firebase iOS SDK, this may be helpful for others:

```swift
extension DatabaseReference {

    func observe(_ eventType: DataEventType, timeout: TimeInterval, with block: @escaping (DataSnapshot?) -> Void) -> UInt {

        var handle: UInt!

        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeout, repeats: false) { (_) in
            self.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
            block(nil)
        }

        handle = observe(eventType) { (snapshot) in
            timer.invalidate()
            block(snapshot)
        }

        return handle
    }

}
```

Usage:

```swift
database.child("users").observe(.value, timeout: 30) { (snapshot) in

    guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
        // Timeout!
        return
    }

    // We got data within the timeout, so do something with snapshot.value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply using a thread?

Allow yourself to assign your call to Firebase from within a thread instance, then in the rare event that the write to Firebase takes *too long* you can just cancel the thread?

```
let thread = NSThread(target:self, selector:#selector(uploadToFirebase), object:nil)
```

. . .

```
func uploadToFirebase(data: Dictionary) {

    // Do what you need to here. Just an example

    db.collection("posts").document("some unique post id").setData([
        "name": "John",
        "likes": 0
    ]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error writing document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully written!")
        }
    }

}
```

Then just create a timer that cancels the thread if the timer fires. If **not**, just cancel the timer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Firebase SDK v6.5.0 and above, you can use **FirebaseOptions's setConnectTimeout** (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.Builder.html#setConnectTimeout(int)).

Sample:

```
Integer connectTimeoutinMillis = 6000; //6 seconds
FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions.builder()
 .setCredentials(credentials)
 .setDatabaseUrl(Application.firebaseSDKDatabaseUrl)
 .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeoutinMillis)
 .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseOptions);
```

Comment: The documentation states: "This setting does not affect the FirebaseDatabase and FirestoreClient APIs." There also seems to be no equivalent option for iOS.