# How to Set Default Timeout?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase **without** the offline feature. Primarily utilizing `.once` snapshots.

Sometimes users may lose cellular coverage, during a snapshot request. Sometimes they're offline entirely when they execute a snapshot request. In both cases, the Firebase client seems to stay in a downloading state indefinitely.

Ideally, I would like a reasonable time out value - with some kind of connection-related error returned. Is there any way to do this?

I'd like to avoid building a presence system, preferring instead a simple error on timeout.

**How can I set a custom timeout value?**

Comment: You can find the related answer in the following link.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895806/how-to-handle-timeout-in-queries-with-firebase?rq=1)